# How can I get the first and second largest input without using list?

Tags: python

How can I get the first and second largest input without using list?

```
li = []
while True:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number (Enter 0 to finish) : "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    else :
        li.append(number)
print("The Largest number is ",max(li))
li.remove(max(li))
print("The Second Largest number is ",max(li))
```

I want to get the largest and the second largest number without using Python list. Also I want the number of times largest number is input.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first,second=0,0
while True:
    number=int(input('Please enter a number (Enter 0 to finish) : '))
    if number ==0:
        break
    if number> first:
        second = first
        first=number
    elif number> second:
        second= number
print(f'The Largest number is {first} \nThe Second Largest number is {second} \n')
```

Comment: This code doesn't give the second largest number correctly. Try it with the following input sequence: `5-4-9-0`

Comment: @Cagri It works fine for me (`9` and `5`), and the logic looks sound. Do you get something different?

Comment: I edited the answer, he did catch a mistake. My bad

Answer (score 1):

```
max, secondmax, temp = -1
numOfMax = 1

while True:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number (Enter 0 to finish) : "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    temp = max
    if number == max:
        numOfMax += 1
    elif number > max:
        max = number
    elif secondmax <= number <= max:
        secondmax = number
    if  secondmax < temp < max:
         secondmax = temp
print("the largest number is {}".format(max))
if secondmax != -1:
    print("The second largest number is {}".format(secondmax))
else:
    print("There isn't a second largest number")
print("The largest number is inputted {} times".format(numOfMax))
```

This one works fine. Let me know if it hits to any bug

Comment: Thank you, how can i print the second largest number?

Comment: How to know the number of times the largest number appears

Comment: Here you go pal! That one finds you max, second max and the number of times the largest number appears. I hope that answers all of your questions